# LinqPad Not Returning Results With C# Statements

Tags: sql, linq

It's late, so this must be something stupid.  I have LinqPad connected up to my database and cannot seem to get results for the simplest of queries.

```
var q = from app in AppInstances
 select new {
 AppId = app.AppId
 };
```

When I run that, LinqPad says that it executed successfully (C#Statement mode).  Nothing is retured.

I can write the following very simple Lambda (C# expression mode):

```
AppInstances.Select (p => p.AppId)
```

And that works.  Why?  I would prefer to use the non-lambda query building functionality.  I am sure that this is something all together silly.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I would expect that in statement mode, you'd have to do something like call `q.Dump();` to see the results.

But if you just want to use query expressions, why not do that from expression mode? Just use an expression of:

```
from app in AppInstances
select new {
    AppId = app.AppId
};
```

Or to make it equivalent to your original lambda:

```
from app in AppInstances
select app.AppId
```

Comment: Wouldn't you know I always forget to take a dump?  q.Dump() did the trick in statement mode.  Thanks John.  Just listened to your DNR podcast, and am making my way through your Functional programming book.  You are a real value to the programming community.