# Enable EntityFramework.DynamicFilters scoped parameters in LINQPad

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linqpad

I have the following `EntityFramework.DynamicFilters` on my multi-tenant data:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    [code removed for brevity]
    modelBuilder.Filter("NegotiationPermissionFilter", 
        (NegotiationPermission np, string userId, List<Guid> groupIds) => 
            (np.ApplicationUserId == userId) || (groupIds.Contains(np.GroupId)),
            () => "", () => new List<Guid>());
}
```

I want to query the data through LINQPad.

How do I configure LINQPad to allow me to set the values of those scoped parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `C# Statement` to LINQPad like this:

```
var groupIds = new List<Guid>();
groupIds.Add(new Guid("283f872c-e3c9-e511-8272-984be10349a2"));
groupIds.Add(new Guid("2c673813-66cb-e511-8274-984be10349a2"));
this.SetFilterScopedParameterValue("NegotiationPermissionFilter", "userId", "b7562160-4416-49aa-9cb8-01bd7db93d59");
this.SetFilterScopedParameterValue("NegotiationPermissionFilter", "groupIds", groupIds);
var q = Negotiations.Include("NegotiationPermissions").Take (100);
q.Dump();
```

Where those GUIDs relate to data in your db.

- Hit F4 to bring up LINQPad's `Query Properties` dialog
- Add an `Additional Reference` to `EntityFramework.DynamicFilters.dll`
- Type in an `Additional Namespace Import` of `EntityFramework.DynamicFilters`
- Click `Set as default for new queries`, if this is going to be a regular thing for you
- Click `OK`.

Hit `F5` to run the query.

Thanks to [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) for [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448206/linqpad-not-returning-results-with-c-sharp-statements/4448228#4448228) that showed me why my data wasn't appearing when I knew it should be.